# Evaluating the Variance the Weighted Average

Tags: probability

**I am interested in learning about how to calculate the Standard Deviation of the Weighted Mean.**

As an example - suppose you only have a sample of people in a city, the sample average income of people in a city, and the sample variance of the average income of people in a city . Now, suppose you have a set of different cities - you can now calculate the Weighted Mean and the Variance of the Weighted Mean in this case.

From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance, https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0224c1c53591c619794682f2bc3560dc86530e2b), I obtained the formula for the Weighted Mean:

$$\mu_x = \frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} \left(\sum_i N_{x_i} \mu_{x_i}\right)$$

$$\sigma_x = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}$$

Since the  Variance of the Mean is equal to the Variance of X divided by sample size, I think you should be able to adapt this formula to calculate the Standard Deviation of the Weighted Mean like this:

$$ \sigma_{\bar{x}} = \frac{\sigma_x}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} = \frac{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_i N_{x_i}} - 1\right) \sum_i \left[(N_{x_i} - 1)\sigma^2_{x_i} + N_{x_i}\mu^2_{x_i}\right] - \left[\sum_i N_{x_i}\right]\mu^2_x}}{\sum_i N_{x_i}}$$

**My Question:** Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct? Have I correctly applied the Laws of Expectations and Variances to evaluate the Variance of the Weighted Mean?

Thanks!